# Oracle correlated query using schema names

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

consider the following correlated query :

```
update CASSETTE.DB_NIM_CABLES a
set( cgb_a, cgb_z ) =
(
    select  regexp_substr( name, '[^ ]+', 1, 1 )
        ,   regexp_substr( name, '[^ ]+', 1, 1 )
    from CASSETTE.DB_NIM_CABLES b 
    where b.id = a.id
) where REGEXP_COUNT( a.name, '-' ) = 1;
```

This works if I run it using the CASSSETTE account, but not with any other. Why is this ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Do you have appropriate privilege to update that table from another account?

Comment: I don't get an error, I see a prompt saying # rows updated, but when I look no rows are updated. I have assigned the proper privileges.

Comment: Are you checking from a different login session and not committing before checking for the change?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because probably the other users (account) with which you want to run the DML don't have the UPDATE and SELECT permission on the table. 
So the CASSETTE user shoud grant the permission to the corresponding user.

I.E., saying that you want to run it from the OTHERUSER schema, you, should

1- connect to DB with CASSETTE USER

2- give the permission as follows

```
            grant ALL PRIVILEGES on DB_NIM_CABLES to OTHERUSER ;
```

PS I give all permission, it should be enough to give SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE.

See this doc, in the part where it talks about OBJECT privileges.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBSEG/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.htm#DBSEG99868

Answer (score 0):

There were duplicate tables, one in the CASSETTE-schema and the other one in GTFIBER. I was updating the table in the GTFIBER scheme and looking for data in the other scheme. Thanks for your time